# How to get code coverage for tests run using QF test tool

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, qf-test

I use QF test tool (http://www.qfs.de/en/qftest/) to run my integrated UI based tests . Is there any tool which can get code coverage of qft test suites ? 
**Note : I use Sonar (jacoco plugin) to get code coverage for Junit tests** . 
I googled a lot and couldn't find any relevant documentation for this . So any links to documentation or example would be helpfull

Comment: QF-Test is known to work with Emma. Have a look at the QF-Test mailing list: http://www.qfs.de/archive/qftest-list/2007/msg00727.html

Answer (score 1):

oYes, this is possible. I'm using QF-Test with Jenkins CI, Sonar and JaCoCo.

To keep it short, in QF-Test go to the step which invokes the SUT and add the -javaagent: parameter to the program

e.g.:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/mvnlib/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.4.201312101107-runtime.jar=destfile=/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/Integration_Build/workspace/your.program.test/jacoco/jacoco-qf.exec,includes=your.packages.*,output=file
```

Configure Jenkins (with Jacoco Plugin) to look for jacoco-qf.exec file.

PS: If you use regular Junit Tests you should combine both the coverage of QF-Test and Junit by this Ant script:

```
<jacoco:merge destfile="${jacoco.file}">
    <fileset dir="${jacoco.report.dir}" includes="*.exec"/>
</jacoco:merge>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply , i had stopped looking into this after waiting for answer for long time . I dont have any knowledge on QF tests , but I run QF tests in command line using batch mode using below command -                su $user -c "/usr/local/qftest/qftest-3.5.7/bin/qftest -batch -J-Xmx2048m -runlog /export/home1/runlogs/+b $user_home/SanityTest.qft"   . So i am unable to understand how can i include "-javaagent"  .  Note : I use Electric commander for CI (so i am running QF test execution using commandline)

Comment: @user2323134 the "-javagent" command has to be given to your SUT (=system under test). So you need to include it to the SUT starting sequence you probably created via the Quickstart Manager ...